# Compare row in df pandas - Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, compare

I try to compare 2 rows to know if the current row = next row -1 .

So i try to do a double loop like :

```
for i in df2 :
     if df2['semaine'].iloc[i] == df2['semaine'].iloc[i+1]-1 : 
         print('ok')
     else : 
         print('no')
```

But it's doesn't work...

Someone know how I can do this comparasion ?

Thx a lot

Comment: Could you please show us the expected output and the result you are getting from your code?

Comment: `df2['semaine'] = df2['semaine'].shift()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
for i in range(0, len(df)-1):
    print('index: {} {}'.format(i, df.iloc[i].equals(df.iloc[i+1])))
```

Comment: "Closing" means something different on this site; it means a question shouldn't be answered. Accepting an answer is optional.